# Can I specify a class wide group on a TestNG test case?

Tags: java, testng

I have a base class that represents a database test in TestNG, and I want to specify that all classes extending from this class are of a group "db-test", however I have found that this doesn't seem possible.  I have tried the @Test annotation:

```
@Test(groups = { "db-test" })
public class DBTestBase {
}
```

However, this doesn't work because the @Test annotation will try to make a bunch of methods into tests, and warnings/errors pop up in eclipse when the tests are run.

So I tried disabling the test, so at least the groups are assigned:

```
@Test(enabled = false, groups = { "db-test" })
public class DBTestBase {
}
```

but then any @BeforeTest (and other similar annotations) ALSO get disabled... which is of course not what I want.

I would like some way to annotate a class as being of a particular type of group, but it doesn't quite seem possible in TestNG.  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Just added a possible solution to your TestNG 'class-wide group' problem. Could you check it out, and tell me if that goes in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is through a custom **org.testng.IMethodSelector**:

Its **includeMethod()** can exclude any method we want, like a public not-annotated method.

However, to register a custom *Java* MethodSelector, you must add it to the **XMLTest** instance managed by any TestRunner, which means you need your own **custom TestRunner**.

But, to build a custom TestRunner, you need to register a **TestRunnerFactory**, through the **-testrunfactory** option.

BUT that -testrunfactory is NEVER taken into account by **TestNG** class... so you need also to define a custom TestNG class :

- in order to override the configure(Map) method,
- so you can actually set the TestRunnerFactory
- TestRunnerFactory which will build you a custom TestRunner,
- TestRunner which will set to the XMLTest instance a custom XMLMethodSelector
- XMLMethodSelector which will build a custom IMethodSelector
- IMethodSelector which will exclude any TestNG methods of your choosing!

Ok... it's a nightmare. But it is also a code-challenge, so it must be a little challenging ;)

All the code is available at [**DZone snippets**](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6446).

As usual for a code challenge:

- one java class (and quite a few inner classes)
- copy-paste the class in a 'source/test' directory (since the package is 'test')
- run it (no arguments needed)

---

**Update from Mike Stone:**

I'm going to accept this because it sounds pretty close to what I ended up doing, but I figured I would add what I did as well.

Basically, I created a Groups annotation that behaves like the groups property of the Test (and other) annotations.

Then, I created a GroupsAnnotationTransformer, which uses IAnnotationTransformer to look at all tests and test classes being defined, then modifies the test to add the groups, which works perfectly with group exclusion and inclusion.

Modify the build to use the new annotation transformer, and it all works perfectly!

Well... the one caveat is that it doesn't add the groups to non-test methods... because at the time I did this, there was another annotation transformer that lets you transform ANYTHING, but it somehow wasn't included in the TestNG I was using for some reason... so it is a good idea to make your before/after annotated methods to alwaysRun=true... which is sufficient for me.

The end result is I can do:

```
@Groups({ "myGroup1", "myGroup2"})
public class MyTestCase {
    @Test
    @Groups("aMethodLevelGroup")
    public void myTest() {
    }
}
```

And I made the transformer work with subclassing and everything.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long... I kinda stopped watching SO for a while :-)

Comment: Mike!!! Mike Stone is back! Glad you like my "solution": it was one of my first code-challenge on SO ;)

Comment: "Modify the build" ? You modify Testng build ? Because the complexity of my solution is there precisely to avoid modifying Testng...

Answer (score 4):

TestNG will run all the public methods from a class with a @Test annotation. Maybe you could change the methods you don't want TestNG to run to be non-public

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the annotation inheritance works for TestNG but this [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20100104232432/http://beust.com/weblog/archives/000170.html) may be of some use.

Actually, this may [help better](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations), look at inheritGroups.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me as the following **code-challenge** (community wiki post):

How to be able to execute all test methods of Extended class from the group 'aGlobalGroup' without:

- specifying the 'aGlobalGroup' group on the Extended class itself ?
- testing non-annotated public methods of Extended class ?

The first answer is easy:
**add a class TestNG(groups = { "aGlobalGroup" }) on the Base class level**

That group will apply to all public methods of both Base class and Extended class.

BUT: even non-testng public methods (with no TestNG annotation) will be included in that group.

CHALLENGE: avoid including those non-TestNG methods.

```
@Test(groups = { "aGlobalGroup" })
public class Base {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @BeforeClass
     public final void setUp() {
           System.out.println("Base class: @BeforeClass");
     }


    /**
     * Test not part a 'aGlobalGroup', but still included in that group due to the class annotation. <br />
     * Will be executed even if the TestNG class tested is a sub-class.
     */
    @Test(groups = { "aLocalGroup" })
     public final void aFastTest() {
       System.out.println("Base class: Fast test");
     }

    /**
     * Test not part a 'aGlobalGroup', but still included in that group due to the class annotation. <br />
     * Will be executed even if the TestNG class tested is a sub-class.
     */
    @Test(groups = { "aLocalGroup" })
     public final void aSlowTest() {
        System.out.println("Base class: Slow test");
        //throw new IllegalArgumentException("oups");
     }

     /**
      * Should not be executed. <br />
      * Yet the global annotation Test on the class would include it in the TestNG methods...
     */
    public final void notATest() {
       System.out.println("Base class: NOT a test");
     }

    /**
     * SubClass of a TestNG class. Some of its methods are TestNG methods, other are not. <br />
     * The goal is to check if a group specify in the super-class will include methods of this class. <br />
     * And to avoid including too much methods, such as public methods not intended to be TestNG methods.
     * @author <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc">VonC</a>
     */
    public static class Extended extends Base
    {
        /**
         * Test not part a 'aGlobalGroup', but still included in that group due to the super-class annotation. <br />
         * Will be executed even if the TestNG class tested is a sub-class.
         */
        @Test
        public final void anExtendedTest() {
           System.out.println("Extended class: An Extended test");
        }

        /**
         * Should not be executed. <br />
         * Yet the global annotation Test on the class would include it in the TestNG methods...
         */ 
        public final void notAnExtendedTest() {
            System.out.println("Extended class: NOT an Extended test");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the @Test annotation at method level that allows for maximum flexibility.

```
public class DBTestBase {

    @BeforeTest(groups = "db-test")
    public void beforeTest() {
        System.out.println("Running before test");
    }

    public void method1() {
        Assert.fail(); // this does not run. It does not belong to 'db-test' group.
    }

    @Test(groups = "db-test")
    public void testMethod1() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Does this works for you or I am missing something from your question.